# FCM onMessageReceived() is never called

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am integrating FireBase Push Notification into my application.
Although I am receiving push notifications(when application is in background) but my onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) is never called, independent of whether application is in foreground or backgroud. 
If its the issue with FCM or there is something that I am doing wrong.
I am using 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0' in my app build.gradle.
I have declared both the services in my application manifest

```
 <service
    android:name="app.pnd.camscanner.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<service
    android:name="app.pnd.camscanner.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: if onMessageReceived never gets called how do you know you get the push messages?

Comment: Does MyFirebaseMessagingService extend FirebaseMessagingService?

Comment: @ArthurThompson - Yes I have already extended FirebaseMessagingService in my FirebaseMessagingService service class

Comment: To be clear, if your app is in the foreground and you send a message to it, you get nothing but if you app is in the background you get the notification?

Comment: @ArthurThompson yes exactly

Comment: Could you add the request you are using to send the messages? Also could you try using the 9.2.0 version of the firebase-messaging library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the issue has been resolved. I have created a new project and integrated the firebase again. Now, when the application is in background, I am getting the push automatically and when application is in foreground, my **onMessageReceived(remoteMessage)** of **MyFirebaseMessagingService** class which extends **FirebaseMessagingService** is being called in which I am generating the push notification by myself.

Answer (score 1):

The issue for me was that i had `tools:node="replace` in the application tag in the manifest